# Need to know which role to enable to get Indexing Section Enabled

Tags: user-management, user-profile, editor-user-permissions

I have a user that we dont want to give admin access to, but still want some of the functionallity from it. The indexing section to where you can boost values, rules and include in search is all greyed out with the priviledges they have know. Could someone point me to what role or security setting they need. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can the user edit other fields on that item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access right applies on the item level, It will make the whole item editable or disabled. Access right does not work on the section level.

It looks like the current user you are logged in with does not have proper access writes to edit the item. You need to identify a role that is blocking the current user from read/write items. You need to use Access Viewer to review user/roles access rights and update roles according to to allow write access.

1. Go to launchpad and click on `Access Viewer`.
2. Select role/user from the top left `Roles and Users` selection box.
3. Select an item that is not accessible for the user/role.
4. It would come up with a right-side pane to show access permission specifically to the selected role/user.

[image]

In most cases `sitecore\Author` role is enough to allow content editing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have added the permissions to this item in the above screenshots and as you can see this person has all the privileges to edit this item.

Comment: Could you check field write access as well? https://byteium.com/2019/05/how-to-restrict-field-write-access-in-sitecore-by-roles

Comment: Ok just checked those to show and they are empty, they dont have a checkbox available for it though either. I checked a user with admin rights and its empty there as well.

Comment: Have you used any custom roles? A few more things to try 1) You can also check if there is any explicit break inheritance applied or any field level security applied (https://sitecoretricks.wordpress.com/2017/12/31/field-level-restrictions-in-sitecore/)(https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2020/08/24/sitecore-field-level-security-give-write-access-to-members-of-a-certain-group/)
. 2) You can remove applied roles one by one to investigate which roles causing the issue, then review the applied access right for the specific role and make it work.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, not sure what is blocking it or allowing it. Seems like only admin role allows it so will just go a different route. Thanks.